# how to customise main menu in vtiger7

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I am new in Vtiger. I want to customize the main menu in Vtiger7.0.I know you will tell me the following way:-

Click on settings->CRMSettings->Configuration->Main menu.

The above way is not required. I want to add 'Tools' in the main menu i.e. 'Tools' will show just like Marketing,Sales etc.
Could you tell me in which way i will do it.

Answer (score 2):

I did not get your requirement clearly. But I have cutomized my menu using following DB tables:

- vtiger_app2tab
- vtiger_tab

other tables you may feel useful, (but I updated my menu using above one table i.e. `vtiger_app2tab` only.)

- vtiger_parenttab
- vtiger_parenttabrel

See the tables' data carefully and understand the relationship and update your menu accordingly.

take a look on [link: Customizing Main Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44532577/vtiger-7-add-custom-module-to-sidebar) too

Answer (score -1):

### Version 7.0

To customize the submenus for change its parent menu, I have used **vtiger_app2tab**.

To know what I must to insert or modify in this table, I searched all the items (submenu options) in **vtiger_tab**. Then I added new records (careful with the sequence field), but didn't delete any.

Why? Because in CRM configuration you have an option to customize the submenus that appears and its easier to hide the submenus that you want.