# vTiger 7 Add Custom module to Sidebar

Tags: crm, vtiger

I have created a module using console.php lets say 'Test'. now i want to add this 'Test' module to the sidebar under 'Sales' Application or may be as a separate Link.

Any help will be appreciated and also guide me where can i find the documentation for customizing my module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, update the table

- vtiger_app2tab

First find out the tab id of the newly created module and update this table.

For examle: (in vtiger_app2tab)

```
53  SALES   7     1
```

this is the database entry (new row) in table `vtiger_app2tab` where tabid if your "test" module is 53.

To know your tabid for newly created module "Test" you can simply view `vtiger_field` table and see the last record of newly created module. There must be fields of your newly created module as well as **tabid** too. This table give you the idea about what is the table name of newly created module and also tabid as well as all the fields associated with the newly created module.

After (these all) inserting new row in `vtiger_app2tab`, got to the settings page>Configurations>main menu using your vtiger admin account. and then you will see your new module on **SALES** app under "Main Menu" configuration page and you can **adjust there**.

You can also use configuration panel.

Comment: Thankyou! In the configuration panel it says no modules Found when i click 'Select Module'

Comment: you need to configure you tabid correctly. What is your tabid and what you have inserted into the db table `vtiger_app2tab`. your new row in this table matters

Comment: Yes i got it Thanks!